# Cannot link when using boost::filesystem

Tags: c++, linux, boost, boost-filesystem

I'm trying to use boost::filesystem::exists function. When I'm trying to link, I'm getting

```
/usr/local/include/boost/filesystem/operations.hpp:289: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
```

error.

I googled for a while and found only "link-with-boost" answers. In my case -lboost_system and -lboost_filesystem specified for linker, but it doesn't seem to work. 
Actually I can use boost::filesytem::path (for example), but when I'm trying to use anything, which needs boost/filesystem.hpp header, I'm getting linker errors.
Any ideas?

P.S. I'm using gcc-4.6.4 and boost lib installed from repos, but I assume gcc-4.6.4 is default gcc version for my ubuntu 12.04. I guess I don't need to compile boost from source?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many options to the linker (ld) to specify the search path to resolve shared libraries, `man ld` will give you all the options.  Suppose you have boost installed in `/usr/local/lib`, you could add one of these options to gcc to pass along to the linker:

- -L=/usr/local/lib

  > Directories specified on the command line are searched before the default directories.  All -L options apply to all -l options, regardless of the order in which the options appear.
  >   If searchdir begins with "=", then the "=" will be replaced by the sysroot prefix, a path specified when the linker is configured. The -L option only sets a compile-time library search path; if you want a shared library to be found at runtime then its directory must be known at runtime.
- -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib

  > Add a directory to the runtime library search path.  This is used when linking an ELF executable with shared objects.  All -rpath arguments are concatenated and passed to the runtime linker, which uses them to locate shared objects at runtime.  The -rpath option is also used when locating shared objects which are needed by shared objects explicitly included in the link; see the description of the -rpath-link option.  If -rpath is not used when linking an ELF executable, the contents of the environment variable "LD_RUN_PATH" will be used if it is defined.

Another alternative is to add to your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` the location of your boost libraries.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib
```

The linker (ld) uses `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as one of the search paths to locate required shared libraries.

You can read more about the linker and shared libraries [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html).

To fully understand why your installation isn't finding the boost libraries by default you might find [this answer at stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104074/confusion-about-linking-boost-library-while-compilation) informative.

This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19643122/locating-boost-libraries-in-ubuntu) suggests using [boost m4](https://github.com/tsuna/boost.m4).

Comment: Thank you, amdn.
You led me to solution. There are two sets of boost library files in my system: /usr/lib and /usr/local/lib. By default /usr/lib is used. So what worked for me is specifying -L/usr/local/lib linker option. 

Please, edit your answer according to my comment, so I can accept it.

Comment: @Farrel Glad my answer was helpful... not sure exactly how you'd like for me to include the solution that worked for you... should it be another alternative or were you suggesting I remove the reference to LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Comment: Just add this solution to your answer and I'll mark thread as answered. LD_LIBRARY_PATH is more true way to fix the issue, I suppose. But for those, who just needs fast fix -L option will work (I just tried to use your methid, but it didn't work for me: maybe I installed boot in a wrong way. I just don't have enough time to deal with it.).